# Filled/Unfilled Rectangle From File

Tags: java, file, while-loop, file-io

The project is supposed to read a file where the first line of the file tells how many rectangle are to be made, and the rest are the dimensions and whether it is filled or not. Assumes a Rectangle class with a toString to format the rectangles. I am getting an input mismatch error on the first line of my while loop, when setting the variable numLines, and need some help.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int columns = 0;
        int rows = 0;
        int numLines = 1;
        String fill;
        boolean filled = false;
        
        //first line of file creates array size
        Rectangle[] rectangle = new Rectangle[numLines];
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner("rectangle.txt");
        
        //reads file 
        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            numLines = inFile.nextInt();
            for (int i=0; i<numLines; i++) {
                columns = inFile.nextInt();
                rows = inFile.nextInt();
                fill = inFile.nextLine();
                if (fill.equals("filled")) {
                    filled = true;
                }
                Rectangle rec = new Rectangle(rows, columns, filled);
                rectangle = new Rectangle[numLines];
                rectangle[i] = rec;
            }

//example of file being read

    6
    6 3 filled
    3 6 unfilled
    4 4 filled
    6 6 unfilled
    9 4 filled
    4 8 unfilled
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am getting an input mismatch error

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner("rectangle.txt");
```

You are creating the Scanner with a text string, not a File. The text string "rectangle.txt" is NOT an int value.

If you want to read from a File then you need to specify a File as a parameter:

```
Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File("rectangle.txt"));
```